# Sql If statement error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Somebody help me to find the error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREAT_SERVIÇO 
BEFORE INSERT ON SERVIÇO 
BEGIN
  if((SELECT MORADA_RUA FROM SERVIÇO)=NULL and (SELECT LOCAIS_ID_LOCAL FROM SERVIÇO) = NULL) = TRUE
   THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'YOU HAVE TO HAVE AN ADRESS OR AN LOCAL');
END IF;
END;
```

ERRORS:

- Error(4,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe
- Error(4,39): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     ) , and or The symbol ")" was substituted for "=" to continue.
- Error(4,50): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe
- Error(4,88): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     ) , and or
- Error(5,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem     and or || multiset
- Error(7,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ;      current delete exists prior

Comment: No need to shout. Also, if you get some errors it would be very helpful to know *what* errors you get.

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: [edit] your question and add the exact error message you get (don't post additional information in comments)

Comment: updated with errors

Comment: There is no `if (select)` construction in PL/SQL. btw your error message `'YOU HAVE TO HAVE AN ADRESS OR AN LOCAL'` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREAT_SERVIÇO 
BEFORE INSERT ON SERVIÇO FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  if(:new.MORADA_RUA is NULL and :NEW.LOCAIS_ID_LOCAL is NULL) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'YOU HAVE TO HAVE AN ADRESS OR AN LOCAL');
END IF;
END;
```

If your trigger is going do disallow inserting when both address and local are null. But to do that is better to use constrain that checks if `ADDRESS || LOCAL` is null.

Comment: I second the suggestion to avoid using a trigger and to go with a constraint instead

Comment: You're right there was `FOR EACH ROW` missing. Try now

Comment: @Boneist Probably as most of trigger questions it is kind of homework ;)